# Using package as store for global variables

Tags: go

I'm learning golang and for my first task I have started to build a simple website. The problem is that I need to have some globals available, I have learned that it is not wise to send these globals using context, as context should be different for every request. Therefore I have thought about creating a package that will be filled with needed variables in main(). I haven't seen this solution in other projects, so I'm asking if this is wrong?
Simple example of config package:

```
package config
var DB *sql.DB
```

And the main:

```
package main
import "project/config"
func main() {
 config.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", conn)
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
}
```

Then I would just import the config package and get the variable wherever I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach. Also you can use init() function instead of main() to initialize your global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that is a very nice solution.